# Convert MySQL to MySQLi in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am a beginner in php and I learn creating registration form from some code samples. My problem is that I do not know how to replace the following lines in old mysql function with mysqli.

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$un','$fn','$ln','$em','$pswd','$d','0')");
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: study from w3school

Comment: If you can send code I can tell you what to change but without that it tough to judge what you are doing

Comment: This isn't the right place to ask for converting of code. I recommend you check the PHP manual for each function and look at the new syntax. That being said, instead of using direct queries, you should use prepared statements for all queries that aren't static (that has variables in them).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `mysqli_query` - syntax almost the same, but if your use procedural style, first parameter - database link:

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
$query = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$un','$fn','$ln','$em','$pswd','$d','0')");
```

Or object style:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$query = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$un','$fn','$ln','$em','$pswd','$d','0')");
```

Also you should not use variables direct in the sql query, use parameters binding:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('',?,?,?,?,?,?,'0')")

$stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $un, $fn, $ln, $em, $pswd, $d);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Thank You very Much

Answer (score 0):

Follow below process

```
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO users ($fName,$lName,$uAge) 
VALUES ('Maruti','somawanshi',27)");

mysqli_close($connect);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your connection link to mysqli_query.

For example:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","db");
```

then pass this $conn to mysqli_query.

```
mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$un','$fn','$ln','$em','$pswd','$d','0')")
```